# Python – Extract Unique values dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, using

Method #1 : Using sorted() + set comprehension + values() The combination of above functionalities can be used to perform this task. In this, we extract all the values using values() and set comprehension is used to get unique values compiled in list.

this is very easy questions maximum all are attempted

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO! Do you have a specific question to ask here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.